# dynamic question and answers html form using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a form with 1 question and multiple answers to this question.
The number of answers for this single question is dynamic, means I can add as many answers as i want to the particular question.

This is the code for the current state

php file:

```
<form class="form" id="send-question">
    <input type="text" name="question">
    <small class="add-answer">add answer</small>
    <div id="append-answers"></div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

js file:

```
$(".add-answer").livequery('click', function(){
        $("#append-answers").append('<div><input type="text" name="answers[]"></div>');
});
```

With this code, when I click the label "add answer", new answer will add to the div.

Now I want to make the question number dynamic also, means not only 1 question with dynamic answers.
lets say another label with "add question" that when i click on that label, new question with its own answers will be added just like it is with 1 question.

I'm really really new with web development and I have no clue how to do it if its even possible.

To make question itself dynamic I know, it will be to change from input name "question" to "questions[]" and create another jQuery for this click.

What I don't understand is how to keep the dynamic answers with dynamic questions and then to correlate between the answers and questions.
I cannot keep the div "append-answers" because each question will have its own div so when I click the add answer to particular question, the new answer will add to the question it belongs, like "append-answers1" and "append-answers2" and so on.

Any help will be much appreciated!

btw, stupid question but how the code knows to jump to the jQuery if it is written in another file. how they are connected (same about ajax)? (I'm coming from C#, C++ world)

Comment: Select the `append-answers` that needs to be updated with something like `$(this).siblings(".append-answers")` so only the sibling element of `add-answer` will be worked on.

Comment: Here's the doc: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: I didn't got you. how this data is stored afterwards so I can map the answers to the questions? and didn't understand how this solve my problem. can you elaborate my code please?

Comment: You said "I cannot keep the div "append-answers" because each question will have its own div so when I click the add answer to particular question, the new answer will add to the question it belongs, like "append-answers1" and "append-answers2" and so on.". What I'm saying is you can keep the same class name. Inside your function, `$(this)` will refer to the `$(".add-answer")` clicked. Then target the next div `append-answers` (instead of all of them) by using `siblings` if you use multiple forms/parents, or `next(".append-answers")` if you put all divs under the same parent.

Comment: First ty, i successfully used siblings (after reading some tutorials) and now it works as expected and add answers to the right question. but now we reach to the second problem - I'll get 2 arrays: questions and answers, how can I map the answers to its corresponding question?

Comment: Use data attributes. In your HTML, inside `add-answer`, add `data-name="array1"` (then array2, etc.) and on click, you can retrieve which was clicked with `var name = $(this).data("name")`. You can then append the right answers with `if (name == "array1")...`

Comment: 2 queations about your idea. 1. How can i append a number to name attribute? I need to manage counter and use it in name attribute. How to do it? 2. I don't know how many question will be. How can i check it with if statement?  If there will be 100 questions?

Comment: You can do `data-id="1"` all the way to 100. Data attributes accept numbers. Then get the number and use it directly to get the right array, or location inside one array, without the need for any if statement

Comment: ty @Will for your suggestion, but I solved it differently. I've created an array of counters, which I filled right before calling to ajax.post on my submit jQuery. I also changed form.serialize() to form.serializeArray() and pushed the counter array to the data sent to ajax. Now for each question I have the number of its answers. Huge thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.